# How to configure multiple sitemaps using MVCSiteMapProvider v4 with StructureMap DI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

The problem, essentially, is that I can't get my sitemap config to support multiple sitemaps.  It's always looking for "default" even when I name my instances and request another.  Now for the background.

I've been pouring over the docs for the new implementation of MVCSiteMapProvider.  They are now using Dependency Injection to configure the SiteMapProvider.  We have an existing StructureMap DI implementation, so I followed the instructions and added, in our case

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
...
x.AddRegistry<MvcSiteMapProviderRegistry>();
...
});
```

Then I started tweaking the MvcSiteMapProviderRegistry.cs file to implement my multiple sitemap scenario.  I have multiple site map files, either will work as long as it's called "default".  If I remove the "default" item then it breaks and complains that "default" is missing.  Which I assume is because it can't find my instance.  Here's how I have them defined.  I suspect the problem is somewhere in here... the loader which it says I have to configure in the Global.asax is looking for ISiteMapLoader  but I'm adding my multiple configuration to SiteMapBuilderSet... anyway here's the code.

```
// Register the sitemap builder
        string absoluteFileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Main.sitemap");
        string absoluteFileName2 = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Test.sitemap");


            var xmlSource = this.For<IXmlSource>().Use<FileXmlSource>()
                       .Ctor<string>("fileName").Is(absoluteFileName);

        var reservedAttributeNameProvider = this.For<ISiteMapXmlReservedAttributeNameProvider>()
            .Use<SiteMapXmlReservedAttributeNameProvider>()
            .Ctor<IEnumerable<string>>("attributesToIgnore").Is(new string[0]);

        var builder = this.For<ISiteMapBuilder>().Use<CompositeSiteMapBuilder>()
            .EnumerableOf<ISiteMapBuilder>().Contains(y =>
            {
                y.Type<XmlSiteMapBuilder>()
                    .Ctor<ISiteMapXmlReservedAttributeNameProvider>().Is(reservedAttributeNameProvider)
                    .Ctor<IXmlSource>().Is(xmlSource);
                y.Type<ReflectionSiteMapBuilder>()
                    .Ctor<IEnumerable<string>>("includeAssemblies").Is(includeAssembliesForScan)
                    .Ctor<IEnumerable<string>>("excludeAssemblies").Is(new string[0]);
                y.Type<VisitingSiteMapBuilder>();
            });

        var xmlSource2 = this.For<IXmlSource>().Use<FileXmlSource>()
                       .Ctor<string>("fileName").Is(absoluteFileName2);

        var builder2 = this.For<ISiteMapBuilder>().Use<CompositeSiteMapBuilder>()
            .EnumerableOf<ISiteMapBuilder>().Contains(y =>
            {
                y.Type<XmlSiteMapBuilder>()
                    .Ctor<ISiteMapXmlReservedAttributeNameProvider>().Is(reservedAttributeNameProvider)
                    .Ctor<IXmlSource>().Is(xmlSource2);
                y.Type<ReflectionSiteMapBuilder>()
                    .Ctor<IEnumerable<string>>("includeAssemblies").Is(includeAssembliesForScan)
                    .Ctor<IEnumerable<string>>("excludeAssemblies").Is(new string[0]);
                y.Type<VisitingSiteMapBuilder>();
            });

// Configure the builder sets
        this.For<ISiteMapBuilderSetStrategy>().Use<SiteMapBuilderSetStrategy>()
            .EnumerableOf<ISiteMapBuilderSet>().Contains(x =>
            {
/*                    x.Type<SiteMapBuilderSet>()
                    .Ctor<string>("instanceName").Is("default")
                    .Ctor<bool>("securityTrimmingEnabled").Is(securityTrimmingEnabled)
                    .Ctor<bool>("enableLocalization").Is(enableLocalization)
                    .Ctor<ISiteMapBuilder>().Is(builder)
                    .Ctor<ICacheDetails>().Is(cacheDetails);*/
/*
                x.Type<SiteMapBuilderSet>()
                    .Ctor<string>("instanceName").Is("MainSiteMapProvider")
                    .Ctor<bool>("securityTrimmingEnabled").Is(securityTrimmingEnabled)
                    .Ctor<bool>("enableLocalization").Is(enableLocalization)
                    .Ctor<ISiteMapBuilder>().Is(builder)
                    .Ctor<ICacheDetails>().Is(cacheDetails);*/


                x.Type<SiteMapBuilderSet>()
                    .Ctor<string>("instanceName").Is("TestSiteMapProvider")
                    .Ctor<bool>("securityTrimmingEnabled").Is(securityTrimmingEnabled)
                    .Ctor<bool>("enableLocalization").Is(enableLocalization)
                    .Ctor<ISiteMapBuilder>().Is(builder2)
                    .Ctor<ICacheDetails>().Is(cacheDetails);
            });
```

In my global.asax.cs I added

```
MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Loader = Resolver.Get<ISiteMapLoader>();
```

and to reference in my view I have

```
 @Html.MvcSiteMap("TestSiteMapProvider").Menu(false, true, true)
```

but it must not be able to find "TestSiteMapProvider" because it always displays "default" or complains if it doesn't exist.

I also thought it might have something to do with the Cache, as I see the filename referenced there, but I don't know how to add multiple instances to the cache, so I just disabled it.  I'm really not doing anything fancy with my sitemaps anyway, and this whole thing is really feeling like massive overkill just to get some flippin automatic breadcrumbs!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was another help doc that I wasn't aware of.  I had completed all of the steps thus far properly, but I also needed to implement ISiteMapCacheKeyGenerator.

See this doc (which wasn't named this when I started.)
https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Multiple-Sitemaps-in-One-Application